# Filter Clearcase message with a Perl regex

Tags: regex, perl

```
version "n:\gill_vob\6_coding\src\p_l\p_l_com\p_l_cc\p_l_cc_msg\src\p_l_can_enable_types.h@@\main\b8519781_22.0\task_gv133946\1"
  created 03-Nov-14.21:26:19 by Kumar (qz7vb1.europe_ccusers@DLG9ZMZN1)
  "Updated CAN signal to include object code signals of D0A40"
  Element Protection:
    User : ASIA\INKARBLR_vobadmin : r--
    Group: ASIA\INKARBLR_ccusers : r--
    Other:          : r--
  element type: text_file
  predecessor version: \main\b8519781_22.0\task_gv133946\0
  Hyperlinks:
    Merge@2092361@\gill_vob <- \gill_vob\6_coding\src\p_l\p_l_com\p_l_cc\p_l_cc_msg\src\p_l_can_enable_types.h@@\main\b8519781_24.0\1
```

I have a set of files which contains data like above.
For the data above, if the word `version` is detected I want to print the data after `Merge@2092361`
i.e

```
\gill_vob\6_coding\src\p_l\p_l_com\p_l_cc\p_l_cc_msg\src\p_l_can_enable_types.h@@\main\b8519781_24.0\1
```

using Perl's regex.

Below is the code i have been trying :

```
my $dir = "C:\\Perl_Play\\label";

find(\&label_checks,$dir);

sub  label_checks
{

$file =  "$File::Find::name\n";

open FILE, $file;

while(<FILE>)
{
$filename = $_;

if(($filename =~ /^version\s/)||($filename =~ /^directory\sversion\s/))
{
if($filename =~ /(")(.*)(")/)
{
print "$2\n";

if($filename =~ /Merge/)
{
print "$filename\n";
print "hello";
}
}

}
}
}
```

The problem with above code is that its not able to the contents after " Merge@2092361@\gill_vob <-".
It is able to identify "version" and print contents after that but its not able to print the lines after  "Merge@2092361@\gill_vob <-".

The below code worked for me:

```
while(<FILE>)

{
$filename = $_;


if(($filename =~ /^version\s/)||($filename =~ /^directory\sversion\s/))
{
if($filename =~ /(")(.*)(")/)
{

print "$2\n";

}    

}
if($filename =~ /(s*)Merge@(\d*)@\\(\w+_\w+)(\s*)->(\s*)/)
{
print "Merged to $'\n";
}

}
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Type `perldoc perlre` at the command line. I would suggest using either the `m` or `s` regex operators, as well as back references. Modify your question above with specific questions about how these should be used, as well as a description of what you've already tried.

Answer (score 0):

It may be easier to get just the merge hyperlinks:

```
cleartool desc -fmt "%[hlink:Merge]p" myfile.cpp
```

which gives

```
"Merge@3937927@\vob1" <- "M:\view\vob1\folder\myfile.cpp'
```

and then just split the string

```
$line = '"Merge@3937927@\vob1" <- "M:\view\vob1\folder\myfile.cpp"';
$line =~ /(.*?) <- (.*)/;
print $1 . "\n";
print $2 . "\n";
```

which gives:

```
"Merge@3937927@\vob1"
"M:\view\vob1\folder\myfile.cpp"
```